# Jquery/Javascript gmail style stuff for message inbox, such as select all message using checkbox etc

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I am enjoying the fact that I'm here building a private message inbox for my website after building a full user signup/login and activation system when a few months ago I thought I wouldn't have enough patience to learn this stuff.

Anyway to my question.
I am currently building the private message inbox for my users and wondering if there are any jquery/javascript stuff I can use to make my inbox more like the gmail inbox.

E.G. Gmail allows you to select all read messages or unread or starred or unstarred or none of the messages using a checkbox. I would like to add this kind of feature to my website and I'm sure the easiest way to achieve this would be using a jquery/javascript script.

I would appreciate if someone could provide some links or info to where I can find several of these types of scripts to use with my inbox page. Thanks

EDIT: Would also like to note that I would like the checkbox to be in a dropdown just like gmails.

Comment: Well done on coming this far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest breaking each requirement you have into pieces (that's general problem solving advice).
So let's take your example. you want to allow a user to select all checkboxes, we want jQuery to select all checkboxes, and select them:

```
$(':checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

Of course, you have to choose where/when you want that to execute, but again, that's a separate part of the problem.

When we uncheck them, we might do something like:

```
$(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

If you want read/unread, you'll want to work on all the selected items, so you'll want something like (of course, in a deployed app, you'd want to make sure that this doesn't grab radio buttons or other checkboxes etc.):

```
$('#read').click(function(){
  $(':checked').each(function(){
    // change their background colour, maybe
  })
});
```

Comment: How would I do this with a checkbox in an actual drop down? The type of selection they would want to make would be one of the items in this drop down.. e.g. read, unread etc

Comment: @Psychonetics, break the problem down: you want to perform a function when you select a dropdown item: $('select').change(function(){...}), you want that functionality to work on all selected checkboxes, use the above code $(':checked')

Comment: Ok works fine, it selects ALL checkboxes when I arrive on the page or refresh the page. Now I need it to do this only when I click the top checkbox. I guess I have to use a function? I found this: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/  which seems to do exactly what I want in a way.

Comment: @Psychonetics, exactly. so your top checkbox should have a unique id, say topCheckBox, and then you create a function when you click it: $('#topCheckBox').click(function(){ $(':checkbox').attr('checked','checked'); }) and you take it from there, maybe add a condition, like so: if the box is checked, then uncheck all (see the code above), else check all

Comment: Having trouble doing the if statement as it's quite different to php.

Comment: how about if ($(this).is(':checked')) checkAll() else uncheckAll()

Answer (score 1):

hi
you can do something like this

```
$("#select-all").click(function(){
      $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

(Haven't tested it though)

Edit: oops! i wrote select by mistake :P
and you can differentiate between read, unread etc by using classes on the them

Comment: How would I put this in a dropdown list?